# how to make Extract.data.frame signal an error for nonexistent columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

If I select a nonexistent column in a `data.frame`, R just returns `NULL` or `NA`s.

```
> df <- data.frame(foo=1:3,bar=4:6)
> df$fooo # note typo
NULL
> df["fooo",] # note typo
    foo bar
NA  NA  NA
```

Sometimes, this leads to bugs that are tricky to find, because R always tries to do something clever with the result.  I would prefer if it signalled an error when I try to extract nonexistent columns, is there a way to do this?

Comment: `df["fooo",]` is for *rows*. What is the behavior you would like to see? `df[, "fooo"]` *will* provide an error.

Answer (score 0):

R is not trying to do anything clever with the result--you're just asking it the wrong question by mixing up row and column extracting order.

Here's your second example, but done correctly. Note the error:

```
df <- data.frame(foo=1:3, bar=4:6)

df[, "fooo"]
# Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , "fooo") : undefined columns selected
```

---

With respect to using the `$` notation, since you're speaking of bugs, I'm expecting that you're writing some sort of script, in which case `[` extraction is generally more reliable since you'll have more control over things like partial name matching. Nevertheless, if you want to be able to throw an error, you could make use of the fact that it will return `NULL` if the value is not found.